# .exe not running through QtCreator and from outside in Qt 4.8.1. issues regarding dll

Tags: qt, opencv, dll, entry-point

I have Qt 4.8.1 installed on a windows 7 64 bit OS. I am using opencv and Qt together for my project. 
For opencv dll's i gave the necessary path and everything in .pro. Everything was working fine until yesterday.
My code gets compiled successfully, but now when i run, it says that abc.exe executed with code -1073741511.

When I manually run the .exe file from debug or release folder it says that some entry point could not be located in QtCore4.dll.

I tried everything, from setting the Qt & opencv Dlls in %PATH% environment variable to copy and pasting the dlls to the same folder to that of .exe

i hav seen the .exe through dependency walker also and it shows me red color in Link checksum field of QtCore4.dll.

Can anybody help me on this?????

Comment: Have you tried inspecting with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or a similar tool?

Comment: If you run from de `debug` folder probably it needs `QtCore4d.dll` (not `QtCore4.dll`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not using (by using i mean copy/add to path) a wrong dll, i mean a dll that was built with a different compiler, example the default (MinGW version) SDK has two versions of QtCore.dll: the correct one (built with MinGW): QT_INSTALL_PATH/qt/bin and one built with some version of VS: QT_INSTALL_PATH/bin (this one is used by Creator and other tools)

Comment: Thanks Zlatomir, it worked. Problem was in some dlls of opencv. i recompiled opencv with mingw and everthing worked fine..still dnt knw why QtCore4.dll was showing error.